# Use git-svn to also control directory versioning

Tags: svn, git, directory, controls

I want to use git-svn to sync my local computer with my company's remote svn repository. I used to do that, but had to stop because git did not put directories under revision control.

The problem is that when I added a new directory git worked just fine, but when I removed a dir the directory would still exist in the svn repository, causing problems to other developers that used svn natively.

Is there a way to solve this? I'm having problems to find solutions in git documentation..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it and it works. Found the solution in:
http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2008/2/23/962754

Basically, you set a variable called svn.rmdir in git configuration. This will make git-svn erase directories on svn server when they become empty.